# Rails 3 Twitter Anywhere For Profile Links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I was using the Twitter Widget for the longest time but I was looking to step it up a level and add additional styling and filtering. Recently I got started with the Rails [Twitter Gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) and so far so good, but I wanted to be able to link back to profiles wherever `@username` appears.

Looking around it seems that [Twitter Anywhere](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome) is the way to go, but I was wondering if there was a better implementation in a Rails environment? Perhaps a gem that loads the required JS files and provides helper methods?

Also I should note that I don't necessarily require all of the functionality that the anywhere api offers, at the moment my main focus is just to provide the @username links (though it is certainly nice to have the option for future expansion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Twitter Anywhere might have been a little overkill for what I was trying to do. All I really needed was the following helper method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034580/i-am-creating-a-twitter-clone-in-ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-code-it-so-that-the)

```
def linkup_mentions_and_hashtags(text)    
  text.gsub!(/@([\w]+)(\W)?/, '<a href="http://twitter.com/\1">@\1</a>\2')
  text.gsub!(/#([\w]+)(\W)?/, '<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\1">#\1</a>\2')
  text
end
```